# Using object identifier as variable name

Tags: java, c++

Just wondering ...

Playing around with C++, I found that if you create a class called `circle`, and then declare a variable named exactly as the name of the class, the compiler does not complain. For example:

```
class circle {
  // whatever it does in here
};

circle circle;   // is a valid statement, but
circle *circle = new circle();  // gives you a 'circle' is not a type complain
```

It turns out that this goes for string string = "string"; as well. And tried it with Java, possible also. I guess it might work on C# too, but I haven't tried.

Can anyone tell me the reason behind this and whether this is an intentional feature?

Comment: `circle *circle = new circle();` Does this not strike you, even a little, as cryptic?

Comment: It does. What I wonder is why "circle circle;" is allowed to work.

Comment: In (almost) all contexts, the compiler can deduce which of those are identifiers and which are types.  So yeah, this is an intentional feature.

Comment: It's impossible in java! `String String = "string" // error`

Comment: @Ilya `String String = "string"` works for me in Java

Comment: @Nawaz The example is in C++, but I also pointed out that it is valid in Java as well, so I thought I can get some opinions from the Java gurus.

Comment: @MooingDuck in that case, why is the dynamic-allocation version not allowed?

Comment: Seems I misread your post and was mistaken.  After the `circle circle` is found, for the rest of that scope `circle` is the object and not the type.  Including the time it finds `= new circle()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n3337 9.1/2

> A class declaration introduces the class name into the scope where it is declared and hides any class, variable,
> function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope (3.3). If a class name is declared in a scope
> where a variable, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both declarations
> are in scope, the class can be referred to only using an elaborated-type-specifier (3.4.4).

n3337 9.1/4

> [ Note: The declaration of a class name takes effect immediately after the identifier is seen in the class
> definition or elaborated-type-specifier. For example,
> class A * A;
> first specifies A to be the name of a class and then redefines it as the name of a pointer to an object of
> that class. This means that the elaborated form class A must be used to refer to the class. Such artistry
> with names can be confusing and is best avoided. —end note ]

So.

```
class circle {
  // whatever it does in here
};

int main()
{
circle *circle;  // gives you a 'circle' is not a type complain
}
```

compiles well.

```
class circle {
  // whatever it does in here
};

int main()
{
circle *circle = new class circle();  // gives you a 'circle' is not a type complain
}
```

compiles well too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason has got nothing to do with dynamic allocation. Rather, it’s illustrated by this code:

```
// declaration    | initialisation
// ---------------+---------------
   circle *circle = new circle(); 
//                  ^
```

At the point marked `^`, the declaration is complete and `circle` is known in the current scope as a *variable*. So you are trying to do `new variablename()` which doesn’t work.